# Is this an appropriate use of an AngularJS Service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have an app with many views that are varied and numerous enough to justify dynamically loading CSS files, based on which view is active at the time.

I looked into various ways of dynamically 'loading' CSS files with angular, and even found a plugin that worked, though it was kind of clunky in its implementation.

I did some research on a native JS way to do this and decided to implement it in a more 'angular way'. I inject the service below into the routes' controller.

Is my method of implementation (using a service) correct? If not, what is the correct venue for logic of this kind?

HTML:

```
<head>
...
    <link id="library-css" href="~/Styles/libraryCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" disabled />
    <link id="results-css" href="~/Styles/resultsCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" disabled />
...
</head>
```

The AngularJS Service:

```
myServices.service("CSSLoader", [function () {

    var cssLinks = {},
        linkToActivate = {};

    (function init() {
        //loading the <link> elements into the cssLinks object for later retrieval
        cssLinks = {
            library: document.getElementById("library-css"),
            results: document.getElementById("results-css")
        };
    })();

    this.loadCSS = function (cssReference, retainPreviouslyLoadedCSS) {
        if (!cssReference) { throw "CSS Link must be provided.";}

        if (!retainPreviouslyLoadedCSS) {
            //first disables any links that are active
            for (var cnt in cssLinks) {
                cssLinks[cnt].disabled = true;
            }
        }

        linkToActivate = cssLinks[cssReference];
        if (!linkToActivate) { throw "CSS Link, (" + cssReference + "), that was provided cannot be found."; }

        linkToActivate.disabled = false;
    };

}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please find a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CoUsdrK1E1xi2K9L15yj?p=preview) I created for you.
It is based on a directive that watches a scope variable that corresponds to its own id.

```
app.directive('disablecss', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('cssToSet.'+attrs.id, function(value,oldvalue) {
```

where the attrs.id corresponds to the link id where the directive is set

```
   <link href="resultCSS.css" id="resultCSS" rel="stylesheet" disablecss />
    <link href="libraryCSS.css" id="libraryCSS" rel="stylesheet" disablecss />
```

The scope attribute is automaticaly modified by the controller associated to the partial views

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/view1', {
        controller:'View1Ctrl', 
        templateUrl:'partial1.html'
    }).
    when('/view2', {
        controller:'View2Ctrl', 
        templateUrl:'partial2.html'
    }).
    otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});


app.controller('View1Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope,$rootscope){
  $scope.cssToSet.resultCSS=true;
  $scope.cssToSet.libraryCSS=false;
}]);

idem for View2Ctrl
```

Do not hesitate if something is not clear.Bye

Comment: I like this solution, it's _even more_ angular! Thanks